# Using Jasmine to spy on a private function in an AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have a factory `myFactory` that has a private function `foo` The factory returns an object with two properties: `foo` - which is set to the private function, and `foo_alias` which is set to 
`function(){ foo() }`

I am attempting to use Jasmine Spies to spy on the private function `foo` through: `spyOn(myFactory, 'foo')` and seeing whether or not it was called via `foo_alias`. I thought since everything is pointing back to the original private function `foo`, that calling the alias should trigger the spy - ie `expect(myFactory.foo).toHaveBeenCalled()` but this does not work.

A plunkr showing this question is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/i032kHYToe5sGml0Mnqn?p=preview

I would really appreciate some help on this and any suggestions for testing a private function through an alias. Specifically, I have a bunch of convenience methods that I want to make sure are calling the internal function with the right parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you just need to make `foo_alias` call `this.foo()`.

The reason is that after spyOn() is called, `myFactory.foo` has been wrapped and replaced by the wrapper function, i.e. `myFactory.foo === wrapped_fn`. The "wrapped_fn" is used by jasmine to "spy" on a function. However, `myFactory.foo_alias` is still calling the original `foo()`, not the spied function. Thus, `expect(myFactory.foo).toHaveBeenCalled()` raises error.

If you make `foo_alias` call `this.foo()` instead, it will then call the correct version of `myFactory.foo()`.